# Bootstrap date range picker get current date the mouse is hovering over

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

**THIS DATE PICKER HAS THE FUNCTIONALITY IM AFTER.** 
http://www.daterangepicker.com/

But Im using [this plugin](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), how do I get current date the mouse is hovering over? For an example if I hover over 23th Feb 2016, how do I get the date 23rd? `getDate` doesnt trigger until I click on a date. So current date on hover? Thanks a lot

**NOTE**

I have jquery-ui and bootstrap datepicker both on the same page so there was a conflict. To resolve the conflict, I am using `bootstrapDP` instead of `datepicker`.

**MY HTML**

```
<div class="home-check-in">
  <div class="search-form-group calendar">
    <span class=" date-dropdown-select">
    <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker2">
      <input type="text" required readonly class="input-group form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" id="FromDate" name="start" />
      <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
      <input type="text" required readonly class="input-group form-control"  placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" id="ToDate" name="end" />
    </div>
    </span> </div>
</div>
```

**MY JS**

```
$('.input-daterange').bootstrapDP({

    startDate: "+0d",
    defaultViewDate : "+0d",
    format: "dd-M-yyyy",
    maxViewMode: 3,
    autoclose: true,
    orientation: "bottom auto",
    disableTouchKeyboard:true,

}).on("changeDate", function() {

    $("#ToDate").focus();   //popup up end date calendar
    var selectedFromDate = $('#FromDate').bootstrapDP("getDate");
    var selectedToDate = $('#ToDate').bootstrapDP("getDate");
    $("#from").val(dateFormat(selectedFromDate,'yyyy-mm-dd'));
    $("#to").val(dateFormat(selectedToDate,'yyyy-mm-dd'));
});
```

Comment: Please add plunker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The datepicker gets stored as a HTML data attribute on the `input` to which it is bound, and thus is accessible with:

```
var datepicker = $('input[name="date"]').data('datepicker');
```

Inspecting the `datepicker` object shows us two useful properties, the first is the `viewDate` property. This merely stores the date of the current month view (no particular day, but that doesn't matter at this stage as we're going to programatically establish that).

The second property we need is the `picker` property. This gives us the DOM node which the picker exists as:

```
var element = datepicker.picker;
```

And from there it's simple DOM traversal to reach the day elements (they are all `TD` elements with the class 'day'):

```
var days = element.find('td.day');
```

So putting it all together, you could get the current day that is being hovered over with:

```
var datepicker = $('input[name="date"]').data('datepicker'),
    element = datepicker.picker;

element.on('mouseover', 'td.day', function(e) {
  var day = parseInt($(this).html(), 10);
});
```

We then need to deal with the fact that the `day` cells can relate to the previous or next months. Fortunately, this is highlighted by the presence of the classes `old` (for last month) and `new` (for next month).

Using that information, combined with the `viewDate` property we discussed above, we can do some date manipulations to establish the current date being hovered over (note the extra checks to ensure we change the year and month if going forward/back a month from the first or last month of the year):

```
var datepicker = $('input[name="date"]').data('datepicker'),
    element = datepicker.picker;

element.on('mouseover', 'td.day', function(e) {
  var hoverDate = new Date(datepicker.viewDate.getTime()),
      day = parseInt($(this).html(), 10);

  // Set the day to the hovered day
  hoverDate.setDate(day);

  // If the previous month should be used, modify the month
  if ( $(this).hasClass('old') ) {
    // Check if we're trying to go back a month from Jan
    if ( hoverDate.getMonth() == 0 ) {
      hoverDate.setYear(hoverDate.getYear() - 1);
      hoverDate.setMonth(11); 
    } else {
      hoverDate.setMonth(hoverDate.month - 1);
    }
  }
  else if ( $(this).hasClass('new') ) {
    // Check if we're trying to go forward a month from Dec
    if ( hoverDate.getMonth == 11 ) {
      hoverDate.setYear(hoverDate.getYear() + 1);
      hoverDate.setMonth(0); 
    } else {
      hoverDate.setMonth(hoverDate.month + 1);
    }
  }

  console.log(hoverDate);
});
```

**Note**: `Date.getMonth()` returns an integer in the range 0..11 (0 being January, 11 being December). This is important to remember.

Comment: Thanks. I have JqueryUI and bootstrap dp on the same page so to resolve the conflict I have used `bootstrapDP` instead of `datepicker`. I changed your code to `bootstrapDP` but it throws an error in console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'picker' of undefined`

Comment: As long as bootstrapDP uses the same underlying datepicker the above should work. Have you changed the input selector to match your one? The first line of code was just a guess as to what your field might be called.

Comment: Hi. actually my input doesnt have `date` is has `start` and `end`. So i tried them but didnt work

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Answer (score 3):

Try this, check the console for output,
fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/9n451jcp/2/

```
var dp = $('.input-daterange');

dp.bootstrapDP({

  startDate: "+0d",
  defaultViewDate: "+0d",
  format: "dd-M-yyyy",
  maxViewMode: 3,
  autoclose: true,
  orientation: "bottom auto",
  disableTouchKeyboard: true,

}).on("changeDate", function() {

  $("#ToDate").focus(); //popup up end date calendar
  var selectedFromDate = $('#FromDate').bootstrapDP("getDate");
  var selectedToDate = $('#ToDate').bootstrapDP("getDate");
  $("#from").val(dateFormat(selectedFromDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
  $("#to").val(dateFormat(selectedToDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
});

$('body').on('mouseenter', '.bootstrapDP td.day', function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
    console.log($(this).text());
  }
});
```

hope this helps..:)

Comment: Incase if autoclose doesn't work after click then use $('body').on('click', '.bootstrapDP td.day', function() {$('.bootstrapDP').hide()});    inside mouseenter function to close manually

Comment: Nice overall, but 1) it helps to show the result in the window, not the console, and 2) the month is not accurate when selecting a date in the old/new month

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','#FromDate td.day',function() {
  var FromDate = $(this).html();
});

$(document).on('mouseenter','#ToDate td.day',function() {
  var ToDate = $(this).html();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

### Got it! [Live demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqsinger/btt7db8k/2/)

The interesting portion of this code is:

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.bootstrapDP td.day', function() {
    var x = $(this); // Save DOM object to variable. Preserve context.

    // Don't show anything for disabled days. Simply return.
    if(x.hasClass("disabled")) { return; }

    // Extract the date info.
    var theDate         = x.text();
    var theMonthYear    = getMonthYear(x); // using helper func.
    var output          = theDate + ' ' + theMonthYear;

    // Show in the UI. Can otherwise use the vars here.
    $("#hoverDate").html(output);
});
```

### Explanation:

You can extract the numeric date from `$(".bootstrapDP td.day")` as shown in the code. The month and date come from `$(".bootstrapDP-switch")` but might differ in case you are hovering over a date from the "last" or "next" month.

Therefore, I've also provided a helper `function getMonthYear` [in the solution code](https://jsfiddle.net/sqsinger/btt7db8k/2/) that will determine if you're in the last or next month and return appropriately. Other months could be extracted from `$(".bootstrapDP-months")` in case of selecting one of the displayed dates that falls within "next" or "last" month.

For the moment, I've maintained that hovering over a disabled date will have no effect. This could be changed by removing the line `if(x.hasClass("disabled")) { return; }`

### Acknowledgment

This solution builds on the previous solution of @mike tracker.